# Inkjet printer: vertical alignment does not work

Tags: maintenance, brother-printer

I have a Brother MFC-5440cn and tried to adjust the vertical alignment with the result that the printing quality now is *very* poor. The printer prints a small shadow next to each letter.

I tried to re-adjust the alignment, but for the 600dpi settings, there is no pattern that matches the 0-pattern (you know what I mean when you've once adjusted a Brother printer).

Is there a way to do a factory reset?

Answer (score 1):

found a solution - ignore the patterns. to the right of the patterns, there are two lines - chose the lines which are closest together. Do this several times and the alignment is ok again :-)